# PHP-FPM fastcgi_finish_request() call clears variables for unknown reasons

Tags: php, fpm

I have a need to save `$_COOKIE["foo"]` in order to process it after request finish.
The example code is next:

```
echo $_COOKIE["foo"]; // all good, cookie shown
fastcgi_finish_request();
$fp = fopen('/tmp/POINTINIT', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $_COOKIE["foo"]); // nothing is written
fclose($fp);
```

Same thing happens with next examples:

```
// Saving it to another variable + adding data
echo $_COOKIE["foo"]; // all good, cookie shown
$foo = $_COOKIE["foo"] . " 1";
fastcgi_finish_request();
$fp = fopen('/tmp/POINTINIT', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $foo); // " 1" is written to the file
fclose($fp);
```

I am doing this in an existent server which I didn't configure and I'm not very good with the whole PHP and PHP-FPM ecosystem.

How does that happen and can I somehow turn global variable scoping?
Thanks.